# AngularJS changing a form action on the submit event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form where the url action come from an API call.

So, in the submit event of the form I need to call an API that receive the URL then I need set the action of the form and trigger the POST.

But, all the steps must run only when the user click on the submit button.

I tried:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="form.submit()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

and

```
angular.module('formCtrl', ['formService', 'authService'])

.controller('formController', function($scope, $http, Form, AuthToken) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.submit = function() {

        Form.get().success(function(data) 
        {
            if (data.url) 
            {

                document.myForm.action = data.url;
                document.myForm.submit();

            }
        });
    }

});
```

But didn't work. Actually, I tried a lot of thing without success.

And I'm not using jquery in my project.

Can some one give me some help in how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `submit` to your $scope and specify `ng-controller` as your controller `formController`

Comment: I'm using ngRoute to set the formControler as my controller. I'm very new in AngularJS. May you give me a code sample to resolve my problem ?

Comment: My main problem is set the URL action before the submit. But I have to set it when the user click on the submit buttom.

Comment: please take look to this example http://plnkr.co/edit/80iUBH9rIZLYGKHRkMv0?p=preview